# How to use wepb images in file-loader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webp, webpack-file-loader

I have a React App. I use a file loader in my project for loading images.

This is how my config looks in the webpack file:

```
module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|mp4)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[path][name].[ext]?[hash]',
                            context: 'myApp',
                            publicPath: '/myApp',
                            useRelativePath: true,
                            emitFile: false
                        }
                    }

                ]
            },

         ...]}
        ...
```

This works fine and I can import images in my components like this:

```
import myImg from '../../images/myImg.jpg';
```

Now I want to use .webp images. I generated them by myself and want to use them in this manner:

```
import myImg from '../../images/myImg.jpg';
import myImgWebP from '../../images/myImg.webp';

<picture className="picture">
   <source type="image/webp" srcSet={myImgWebP} />
   <source type="image/jpg" srcSet={myImg} />
   <img src={myImg} />
</picture>
```

I changed file-loader config and added there 'webp' extension, but it doesn't work:

```
module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|webp|gif|svg|mp4)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[path][name].[ext]?[hash]',
                            context: 'myApp',
                            publicPath: '/myApp',
                            useRelativePath: true,
                            emitFile: false
                        }
                    }

                ]
            },

         ...]}
        ...
```

Now when I build my project I get "Invalid or unexpected token" error:

```
* /Users/user/Work/site/myApp/images/myImg.webp:1
* RIFF�b
*     ^
* 
* SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
*     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:23)
*     at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
*     at Object.newLoader [as .js] (/Users/user/Work/site/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:104:7)
*     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
*     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
*     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
*     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
*     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
*     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Work/site/myApp/MyComponent.js:26:1)
```

Comment: Anna, have you found the solution?

Comment: @SergeyGubarev, I updated versions of the packages, posted them in the answer

Answer (score 2):

For those who are facing the same problem - I was able to fix it when updated packages which I use for the build to the following versions:

```
"file-loader": "2.0.0",
"webpack": "4.43.0",
"babel-plugin-file-loader": "1.1.1",
```

Here is file-loader settings:

```
{
    test: /\.(png|jpg|webp|gif|svg|mp4)$/,
    use: [
           {
               loader: 'file-loader',
               options: {
                 name: '[path][name].[ext]?[hash]',
                 context: 'myApp',
                 publicPath: '/myApp',
                 useRelativePath: true,
                 emitFile: false
               }
           }
         ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `webp-loader`:

```js
{
    test: /\.(png|jpg|webp|gif|svg|mp4)$/,
    use: [{
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
                name: '[path][name].[ext]?[hash]',
                context: 'myApp',
                publicPath: '/myApp',
                useRelativePath: true,
                emitFile: false
            }
        },
        {
            loader: 'webp-loader'
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The file-loader resolves import/require() on a file into a url and emits the file into the output directory.

install file-loader:
npm install file-loader --save-dev

refer the Link:https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/

Comment: I use a "file-loader" in my project, the problem is it doesn't work exactly with .webp images, for other images (.jpg, .png) it works.